# Architecture of the iOS application that communicates to the server

Tags: ios, swift, mobile

I have a general architecture question. From where applications like Skype or Viber delivers user images?

For example, if I am a user that registers in the application and I set my profile image - then that image is uploaded to the server.

When I open my list of contacts (that is fetched from the server), how are images served? Are they served from some url all the time or they are downloaded and cached on the mobile device?

What do you think, which approach is better. And maybe there is a third approach that I am not aware of.

Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Why downvoting? I think that I clearly explained the problem that I am considering how to solve.

Comment: I haven't down voted you, but I do think this is a bit of a broad question. If you can be more specific it would help others answer you in a way that's helpful for everyone.

Comment: No, you did not explain any "problem" in a good way. But you might want to look into caching.

Comment: Well, I want to find out how the images are served in Skype list of contacts for example. It is maybe not so specific question, but that is only because lack of my knowledge to ask more specific.

Comment: Many apps that have profile images cache them. [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) is a good option.

Comment: Your question is rather OT because it doesn't really involve programming: for example, had you asked about an implementation issue _you_ ran into, it would be fine. Please take a look at the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular the "Asking" section.

Answer (score 1):

Its common practice to cache that kind of content at least while the app is in memory.  Whether to retain it between runs depends on the cost of fetching again and the probability of needing it.

Comment: Okay, thanks. One more thing that I asked in the question. Are images actually downloaded to the device or served from some url all the time in the application? So, do I cache image url or I download the image and then I use it from the phone? Thanks!

Comment: Its always downloading from some resource, then operating system of your devices puts it in cache, and when your want to open this url again, you will instantly get image from cache. Usually you won't know about realisation of all this network & cache stuff; all you have to do in application code is to choose, should your system use cache or not.

Comment: "downloaded" and "served from a url"  are two halves of the same action.  To present a remote image,  it must be served, *and* it must be downloaded.  The main design question is how long to keep it locally (to avoid subsequent serving and downloading).

Answer (score 1):

Hope i'm understand your question. I see these ways:

1. You can use some third-party services to get user's picture by his email or some other information; for example: https://gravatar.com/.
2. It's similar with 1: You are linking your user with his profile in some social network, Facebook for example. Then you can get access to his avatar and contact list, which includes avatars of his friends.
3. You are uploading and saving pictures of users by you own.

All apps definitely doing in these ways. In any case, mobile app stored pictures in his cache or file system, it helps your app not to downloading a new copy of images each time. Usually, it's cache: they will not download resource if no change was made. Http protocol has special header ('modified-since' AFAIK) for it.